# How to navigate flutter screen on tap of any home_widget widgets

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm encountering a problem while implementing navigation within a widget added to the device's home screen using the home_widget package in Flutter. The widget consists of two buttons: a profile button and a settings button.

[image: Home widget design]

Expected Behavior:
Upon clicking the profile button, users should be navigated to the app's profile screen. Similarly, clicking the settings button should navigate users to the app's settings screen.

Current Issue:
Despite implementing the necessary code to handle navigation within the widget using the home_widget package, I'm facing difficulties in achieving the desired navigation behavior. Clicking on the profile or settings button within the widget does not trigger the expected navigation.

Steps Taken:

1. Utilized the home_widget package to enable widget creation and management on the home screen.
2. Designed the widget to include a profile button.
3. Configured the widget to handle navigation upon clicking the profile button using 'HomeWidgetLaunchIntent.getActivity'.

```html
val pendingIntent = HomeWidgetLaunchIntent.getActivity(
    context,
    MainActivity::class.java
)

setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnProfile, pendingIntent)
```

I'm seeking assistance in identifying a solution or workaround to pass data along with the navigation request within the home_widget package.